# Height:100% and Sticky Footer layouts. The final battle

Tags: html, css

CSS wonderland. My dream is to understand at least the 100% layout with sticky footer and header. I've been browsing the web and found five+ different ways to do that.

http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

http://www.visibilityinherit.com/code/height-stickyfooter-centered.php

http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

http://bonrouge.com/hcf-fluid.php

I believe that there is some kind of common denominator. I want all the planet to know it!

I ask you to compare these practices deeply and can tell what pitfalls each one contains. Which problems can happen with each layout?  Is it possible to break it using floats inside, etc? What shouldn't I do with it? Which browser are not covered?

Examples are required

Comment: Ughh...how I dislike CSS.  And this is the reason why.  That said, I do hope you get some good answers.

Comment: I'm not really sure why someone would want to spend time on this question. Just pick the first option and use it. Been using it for a long time and never had problems. Works on all common browsers, including IE6.

Comment: University thesis days are back! =)

Comment: @Tom -Although the first is (in my opinion) the best solution to this age old problem, it does not stretch the center div's height to 100%. thus it too has its problems.

Comment: @Partack: true, but I think that's a different challenge altogether, no longer a footer issue but getting content to stretch to 100% of height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common aspect of these is that margins are not included in the height of an element and can be negative. Setting the height to 100% sets the height of the content wrapping div to same height as the screen. Applying a negative margin to the element means that the next sibling begins within the element.

In the first example the content wrapper is div#wrapper and its next sibling is div#footer. First the height of the wrapper is set to the height of the screen (applying 100% height to #wrapper, body and html). This would cause the wrapper to take the entire view port and the footer to be out of sight. Applying a negative margin equal in value to the height of #footer moves the footer element up the page so that it is back within view.

Answer (score 0):

I once found an amazing template that amazingly works on all browsers, even IE6, I cant remember the link, but here is the CSS and the HTML for it:

CSS:

```
body, html{
height: 100%;
}

body, p {
margin: 0; padding: 0;
}   

#wrapper {
min-height: 100%;
}

* html #wrapper {
height: 100%;
}


/*HEADER------------------------------------*/
#header {
width: 100%;
background: #666;
}

#header_900 {
width: 960px;
height: 100px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}

/*FOOTER------------------------------------*/
#footer {
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
margin: -100px auto 0 auto; /*THIS SHOULD BE EQUAL TO THE FOOTERS HEIGHT*/
position: relative;
background: #666;
}

#footer_900 {
width: 960px;
height: 100px;/*THIS IS THE FOOTERS HEIGHT*/
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
}

/*CONTENT------------------------------------*/
#content {
width: 100%;
padding-bottom: 100px; /*THIS SHOULD BE EQUAL TO THE FOOTERS HEIGHT*/
}

#content_900 {
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="wrapper">


    <div id="header">
        <div id="header_900">
            <p>header</p>
        </div><!--header_900-->
    </div><!--header-->


    <div id="content">
        <div id="content_900">
            <p>content</p>
        </div><!--content-->
    </div><!--content-->


</div><!--wrapper-->


<div id="footer">
    <div id="footer_900">
        <p>footer</p>   
    </div><!--footer_900-->
</div><!--footer-->


</body>
```

Comment: awhh. for a moment I thought this stretched the content div 100%. But after changing the background colour, you can see it does not.

this is really no better than the Ryan Fait solution =(  oh well.